# Освободить память после dbContext.Refresh

Tags: c#, entity-framework, vb.net

Добрый день!

Примерный код:

```
dbContext.Refresh(Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, dbContext.Collection1)
dbContext.Refresh(Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, dbContext.Collection2)
dbContext.Refresh(Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, dbContext.Collection3)
```

после этого программа увеличивается в размерах в оперативной памяти до 700 Мб примерно; после закрытия формы, в которой выполняется данный кусок когда, делаю

```
dbContext.Dispose()
```

однако, размер программы в памяти не меняется.

```
GC.Collect()
```

не помогает.

Будьте добры подсказать, как правильно выгружать контекст БД из памяти. Спасибо.

**P.S.** Помощь принимается <strike>в любой валюте</strike> на любом языке фреймворка .NET (C#, VB)

Comment: попробуйте `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
 GC.Collect();`

Comment: Спасибо, но  тут есть одно "но": свойство GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode поддерживается только в версиях фреймворка 4.5.1+ [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx), а мне категорически необходимо написать эту программу версии .NET Framework 4 И не выше

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про то, как устроен сборщик мусора (поколения, хранение больших объектов), чтобы понимать, что сборщик мусора обычно ничего не чистит, только помечает. А чистить память начинает, когда память под что-то становится нужна. Неработающее приложение в течение получаса не требует новой оперативки, ну вот он и не шибко и торопится чистить ваши 750 мб. А ещё почитайте вдумчиво этот комментарий PashaPash: https://habrahabr.ru/post/125968/#comment_4148925

Comment: Всегда так и делал, а именно не беспокоился по вопросу управления памятью и отдавал это на суд сборщика мусора, пока в руки не попался код программы на VB.NET, которую необходимо переделать и которая уходила в ступор и жутчайший подвисон после 20-30 минут работы, что лечилось только перезапуском программы.. В коде было очень много Dispose, но мусорщик так ничего и не убирал..

Comment: А профайлер что говорит? Какая именно память занята: LOH?

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в любом случае сборщик мусора освобождает память в подходящий для этого дела момент=> вызвав Dispose ты говоришь, что объект тебе не нужен, но не инициируешь удаление объекта из памяти.

Однако, сам процесс освобождения памяти при этом может не произойти моментально, дело в том, что этот процесс дорогой=> выполняется, когда в этом есть действительная потребность.

Comment: Запустил свою программу, выполнил метод с рефрешами, позакрывал лишние формы, оставил только главное пустое MDI-окно и ушел на обед - за 30 минут высвободилось только около 200 Мб (было ~720 Мб, стало 515 Мб).. У меня, видимо, ленивый сборщик мусора

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нужен код полностью. Видно, что Dispose контекста не помечает на удаление объекты элементов коллекции. Это значит, что в памяти остаются ссылки на элементы, поэтому и мусора никакого нет.